# How do I dissolve this face

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

How do I dissolve this face into the surrounding face?[image]

Whenever I try to dissolve it (Delete > Dissolve Faces) it gives me an error: "Can't create merged face"

Comment: Yeah, using complex huge NGons like that is gonna cause lots of problems for modelling, and only create trouble down the road. Learn to use [proper tolopoly](http://topology-guides.tumblr.com/) if you plan to successfully model with meshes.

Comment: So I was trying to create a large maze layout and then extrude it. I created a plane, subdivided it a bunch and carved out my maze, then after merging all my faces together i got stuck with this. Is there a better way to create a maze layout?

Comment: If your maze is gonna be "tile based" or follow some sort of "grid layout" best is starting from a large plane subdivided into a regular grid of squares. You can then carve each tile from exactly one square and not end up with a mess like that.

Comment: Oh, that's what i did each tile is 1/8 of a grid square. Its better not to merge the squares afterward though? It seems as though it would create less of a mess instead of more.

Comment: Never merge squares, mesh models should always be based on quads (4 sided faces) as much as possible. Occasional triangles are ok, more than 4-sided faces are to be avoided in final work in most situations. They are  Ok as a step towards an end.

Comment: So a grid of 4096 squares with some removed is better than 1 large n-gon?

Comment: It is. It may seem like you are saving geometry with the ngon but in truce you are not. Add a *Triangulate* modifier to your mesh and you will see what I mean. The geometry is all still there, and will look far worse, not to ention you can't really export ngons anyway.

Comment: Yes it definitely seems as though the ngon would be better. Thank you.Umm do I need to close the discussion somehow?

Comment: @Sam no need to close anything, although it would be good to get this discussion written up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may seem as though having a complete flat Ngon is preferable, it is far better to keep the most basic shapes and not merge them together.

(Thank you to Duarte Farrajota Ramos for this)